# Use express middleware morgan from exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, morgan

I'm planning to use `morgan` for logging purpose in `express` application.
I am able to use `morgan` in `server.js` file as: `app.use(morgan('tiny'))` and it works fine. However I want to put all logging related middleware into file called `logger.js`and use from it, without complicating `server.js` file.

So `logger.js` looks as follows:

```
import morgan from 'morgan'
import express from 'express'

exports.morganLogger= function(req, res, next){
   morgan('tiny')
   next()   // Also tried commenting: next()
}
```

and use in `server.js` by `import morganLogger from './logger'` and tried `app.use(morganLogger)` and `app.use('\', morganLogger)` but it vain as it turn out to be not correct syntax for integrating middle-ware! 

 Either getting `TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))` when `app.use('/', morganLogger)` and `TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function` when `app.use(morganLogger)`.

Is there a way to resolve this and use `morgan` as `express` middleware from external `js` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a return parameter for the middleware.

If you are planning on using only 'tiny' format of morgan, then there is no need to separate it out the different file.Try this in the server.js,

```
app.use(morgan('tiny'))
```

Comment: I am not just using `morgan(tiny)`. That was just as an example. Anyway I am using winston logger as well and want all of logging config in one place